# What data is available to a Facebook app after permissions are granted?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, android-facebook, facebook-permissions

Imagine I have a mobile app, and then I create a new Facebook app, which I use to login users through it. In order to log into the app, users have to grant **user_likes** permission.
Then, I can access their user_likes with a request to the facebook graph using the **app_token**. I've tested this. But also, I realized that only the user_likes set to "public" are shown. All the user_likes that are private or only friends, are not shown.

Is this the intented behaviour? I mean, if some user granted me access to user_likes and he didn't revoke explicitly the permission after that, should I be able to get the user_likes anyway or no?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an User Access Token, not an App Access Token. That's what they are for.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, with the user access token I can retrieve that data, but if I need to run some code on the server side of my mobile app (for instance to hide/show info depending on user_likes), it would be easier to get with that app_token, than store (and revalidate when expires) the user access token for each user on the app. However, for what I've read so far, and you're response, it seems that there's no other way.

Comment: As I said, you cannot get the data from an App Access Token, because it doesn't contain the user permissions, which are an essential concept of OAuth. Why don't you add the User Access Token to the request from your mobile app to your server, and the server uses this to query the info? Please accept my answer if it was useful to you. Thanks.

Comment: Yes Tobi, that's what I thought from the very beginning. Just asked to see if this was possible with app_token instead of the former approach with just it's a little more cumbersome, and I didn't found a clear answer for my doubt before.